# php remove element from array using regular expression

Tags: php, arrays, regex

i have the following array

```
(
[0] => DHL - 4857998880
[1] => DHL - 4858005666
[2] => COA - 485344322
)
```

i want to loop through the array and if DHL found then i want to remove from the array. the numbers in front of DHL do not matter. any element with DHL in front i want to remove from the array.

i have created the following the regular expression to ignore the numbers in front but not sure how move forward from there.

```
foreach($result as $valDHL) {

   $s = preg_replace("/[^a-z-]/i", "", $valDHL);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to strip out the entries in your array that start with `DHL`, using the regex `^DHL` to see if the entry starts with `DHL`:

```
$array = array(
0 => 'DHL - 4857998880',
1 => 'DHL - 4858005666',
2 => 'COA - 485344322'
);
$array = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return !preg_match('/^DHL/', $v); });
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [2] => COA - 485344322 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/I48Ke)